# Which logic has $K$ as modal companion?

Tags: logic, modal-logic

I'd like to understand the modal logic $K$ better. Some modal logics appear as "modal companion" of some superintuitionistic logic. Is there some logic over the classical propositional language (i.e. without the modalities) which has $K$ as modal companion? Or is there some logic over the classical propositional language, which has frame semantics similar to intuitionistic logic, but over the class of all Kripke frames, like $K$? Does the Gödel-translation need to be adapted to achieve this?

With classical propositional language I mean the set of fornulae generated by countably many propositional variables, the constant $\bot$ and the binary operations $\land, \lor, \to$.

Update:  I found the "basic logic" by Visser, which has $K4$ as modal companion. This logic does not satisfy the usual modus ponens, but only a weakened version of it. One can probably adapt the definitions to obtain an even weaker logic which has $K$ as modal companion.

Comment: See https://blog.burakemir.ch/2020/06/kripke-semantics-and-tableaux-for.html?m=1 for a look at Intuitionistic semantic tableaux. Simply removing the reflexive and transitive properties of the accessibility relation yields the propositional analogue to system K.